# Setting DateTime to Certain Value

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using joda time to compare an array of dates.  My goal is to go through the array and see what dates are missing.  I plan on accomplishing this by assigning the first variable in the array to a `DateTime` variable, then counting up the array and Date Time.  If the `DateTime` equals `array[x]`, then both the `DateTime` and the array will increment by one.  If the `DateTime` does not equal the array (meaning that a date is missing) the `DateTime` will increment by one and print out the date until `DateTime` equals `Array[x]`.  At the moment though, I am just trying to get it so that the first date (at holder[2]) is the value of `DateTime firstDate`.

My question is how do I make it so that I can assign `holder[2]` to `DateTime firstDate`? Simply assigning `firstDate` to `holder[2]` is returning an error.

```
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMDD");
String date = dtf.print(firstDate);

String fake;

while ((fake = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] holder = fake.split(" ");

    firstDate = holder[2]; //******the issue******
    System.out.println(firstdate);

}
```

Important things about my code:

1. I am using a `BufferedReader` to take information in from a very large file (20gb) so I am reading in from the text file line by line (and for each line `holder[2]` is the date)
2. The format of the Date on the text file is in yyyymmdd and I want to compare the string of that to the string of `DateTime` (thus the first thing I need to do is assign the first value of the array to `DateTime` which just happens to be my question).
3. I have correctly setup Joda Time

Comment: Your format contains only year, month and date. Why don't you use `LocalDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have in `holder[2]` is a string representation of a date with format "yyyyMMDD", then you need to use the formatter you defined:

```
firstDate = dtf.parseDateTime(holder[2]);
```